# Why talking BCS Hamiltonian doesn't conserve particle number?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity

The BCS Hamiltonian reads:

$$H_{BCS}=\sum_{k\sigma}\epsilon_k c_{k\sigma}^\dagger c_{k\sigma}-\Delta^*\sum_k c_{k\uparrow}^\dagger c_{-k\downarrow}^\dagger+h.c.$$

The particle number operator reads:

$$
\hat{N}=\sum_{k\sigma}c_{k\sigma}^\dagger c_{k\sigma}
$$

The Heisenberg equations of motion reads:

$$
\frac{d \hat{N}}{dt}=i[H,N]=2i(\Delta^*\sum_k c_{k\uparrow}^\dagger c_{-k\downarrow}^\dagger-h.c)
$$

Taking the average respect to the wavefuction, the right hand side is perfectly zero.

**So why saying the particle number is not conserved?**

Comment: The fact that $[H, N]\neq 0$ already says the particle number is not conserved. Nothing else is needed to make the statement. Also, if you compute $\langle \sum_k c_{k\uparrow}^\dagger c_{-k\downarrow}^\dagger\rangle$ on a BCS wavefunction $(u_k + v_kc_{k\uparrow}^\dagger c_{-k,\downarrow}^\dagger)|0\rangle$, the answer is not zero.

Comment: @MengCheng Thanks, I noticed the definition of a conserved quantity in quantum mechanics. So what my question really claim is that the average particle number is not change with time, but it may flutuates around this mean value.

Comment: OK, but that does not say anything: the expectation value of any physical quantity, as long as the state is stationary (i.e. time-independent), does not change with time.

Comment: @MengCheng Thanks again for this further clarification.